# How do i fix the issue bellow during "sudo apt update"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, package, apt

Err:15 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/bhdouglass/indicator-remindor/ubuntu jammy Release

404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt jammy-pgdg InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
W: https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt/./InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: http://apt.kubernetes.io/dists/kubernetes-xenial/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/bhdouglass/indicator-remindor/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this commands before doing the `apt-get update`.

`curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -`

`cat <<EOF >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list`

`deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main EOF`

Comment: Hi thanks, I go these "Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
E: This command can only be used by root."

Comment: use this command to be the root `sudo su -` then try again the commands above.

Comment: I have been able to fix the ppa issue by removing it via apps and repository gui. The remaining issue still persist after running apt-get update. But i'm able to work normally.